# how to generate json data for a form fields in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I am new to JSON data so please help me out!!
   I have single web page with multiple forms which are validated using angularjs,
I want to generate JSON data for the fields in that forms.So which methods should be used to generate JSON data and post syntax for that methods.

my html code is like

```
<td >
<input type="text"  style="width:100px" ng-model="cost"  ng-disabled="status!=true" required>
</td>
<td >
<input type="text"  style="width:110px" ng-model="price" ng-disabled="status!=true" required>
</td>
```

My angularjs code is

```
  var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', ['ngFlag']);

// create angular controller
validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

$scope.style
{
    $scope.buttonCSS= "clicked";
};
$scope.style2
{
}
$scope.invoice = {
    items: [{
         loyality: [{name:'points'},{name:'credits'}],
         value:0,
    period: [{name:'activity1'},{name:'activity2'}]
        }],
        items1:[{currency: [{name:'point'},{name:'credit'}],   value1:0   }]

};
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

Angular allows you to bind your `ng-model` fields as part of an object.  So instead of binding each form field to an individual value.  Make them each an attribute in a single object.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myForm.productName"/>

<input type="text" ng-model="myForm.productCount"/>
```

You then have a JSON object `myForm` that has all the values from your form and can be accessed from the `controller`.

Answer (score 2):

Read about `ng-model` and how two way binding works.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="yourobj.name"  />
<form name="myForm" ng-click="submit()">
```

And in your `controller`, you could grab the form input fields like below.

```
(function(){

   angular.module("yourapp").controller(['$scope', function(){

     $scope.submit=function(){
        var jsonData = $scope.yourObj;  
        console.log(jsonData); 
     }

   }])

})();
```